# Add an htmlwidget from R to a PowerPoint Slide

Tags: r, powerpoint, graphviz, reporters, diagrammer

How can I add the htmlwidget diagram output from DiagrammeR::grViz() to a PowerPoint slide? I'd prefer to keep vector graphics and minimize manual touches.

The code in `main.R` below renders the DOT diagram nicely as an `htmlwidget`

```
# ./code/digraph-test.dot 
digraph my_plot_name {
A->B->C;
}

# main.R
library(DiagrammeR)
digraph_test <- grViz("./code/digraph-test.dot")
```

I'd like to add this output to a PowerPoint slide. I adapted the following code from [this post](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/204551627-Add-option-Export-Save-Plot-as-Powerpoint-using-functionality-of-ReporteRs-package).

```
library( ReporteRs )
require( ggplot2 )
mydoc = pptx( )
mydoc = addSlide( mydoc, slide.layout = "Title and Content" )
mydoc = addTitle( mydoc, "Plot examples" )
myplot = grViz("./code/digraph-test.dot")
# myplot = qplot(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length
#                , data = iris, color = Species
#                , size = Petal.Width, alpha = I(0.7))
mydoc = addPlot( mydoc, function( ) print( myplot ), vector.graphic=TRUE)
writeDoc( mydoc, file = "test plot.pptx" )
```

It produces the following error:

```
Error in .jcall(slide, "I", "add", dml.object) : 
  javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 2; The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.]
```

It seems some people have success with the [LiveWeb add-in for PowerPoint](http://skp.mvps.org/liveweb.htm). I ran into the ActiveX issue, only found hack solutions, and chose not to pursue. There must be a straightforward solution, right?

Comment: Why not use [an RMarkdown slide format](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/gallery.html)?

Comment: @alistaire I wish I could. Unfortunately, I'm required to add PowerPoint slides to a much longer PowerPoint presentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as suggested by @alistaire, Rmarkdown would be a better solution for this graph but if you need it in PowerPoint, I suggest using package webshot to get it as a png file.

```
library(DiagrammeR)
library( ReporteRs )

mydoc = pptx()
mydoc = addSlide( mydoc, slide.layout = "Title and Content" )
mydoc = addTitle( mydoc, "Plot examples" )

# compute new size for image to fit in ppt shape ----
shape_dim <- dim(mydoc)$size
shape_height <- setNames( shape_dim["height"], NULL ) * 72 
shape_width <- setNames( shape_dim["width"], NULL ) * 72

# reuse the shape dimensions in grViz call ----
digraph_test <- grViz("digraph-test.dot", width = shape_width, height = shape_height )
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(widget = digraph_test, file = "digraph.html", selfcontained = TRUE)
webshot::webshot(url = "digraph.html", selector = '.html-widget-static-bound', file= "digraph.png")


mydoc = addImage( mydoc, filename = "digraph.png" )
writeDoc( mydoc, file = "test plot.pptx" )
```

Comment: David, why did you choose 500x300? I tried adapting your code to have the diagram fill a full PowerPoint slide (using a custom full page content slide layout template). I found that 960x540 filled that slide perfectly. But the resulting diagram was off-center. Any idea what's up?

Comment: I've updated the example so that it adjust to size of the ppt shape - I think it's better to control the size

Comment: This worked perfectly for me (I adapted your code to fill a full PowerPoint slide based on [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42892913/fill-an-entire-powerpoint-slide-with-an-r-plot)). Item was perfectly centered. Super useful!

Comment: Thanks for this, David. I know this is likely very ignorant of me but ...! 

If I wanted to use your wonderful `ggiraph` to create an interactive ggplot with popups, is there any way to get that interactive into PowerPoint, whilst preserving the interactivity? (I've tried the above but it didn't bring-through the popups.)

Once more, apologies if this is ignorant and genuine thanks for ggiraph.

Comment: BTW, if you want me to add this as a separate question, please say so

Comment: @p0bs no, it would require a MS add-in (to my knowledge)

Comment: OK - much appreciated